# Creating 2 symbology in the same layer on Mapinfo

Tags: layers, symbology, gps, mapinfo, fields-attributes

New to MapInfo, I would like to create a High voltage layer with two different attributes (11 and 6.6) representing by two different colours on MapInfo. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First, add your table to the map window. Then create a **thematic map** from that layer using the required attribute column. In the thematic map dialog window you can set up the styles you require for the individual values.

The `Create Thematic Map` option can be found under the `Map` menu in older versions of MapInfo (32 bit). In newer versions (64 bit, with the ribbon menu) this can also be found under the `Map` menu but is now called `Add Theme`.

Comment: where can I find the thematic map dialog window please?

Comment: I've updated my answer with instructions on where to find the thematic map function.